# Caliburn Micro: "children" VM in a main shell VM

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm beginning with Caliburn.micro and I'm a bit confused. Say I have a UI with 2 panes, e.g. (this is a fake sample) CustomersView and CustomerView, and 2 corresponding VM's, CustomersViewModel and CustomerViewModel.

Now, say I want to include both panes into a main shell, which should be able to access all the VM's like data members: e.g.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  private CustomerViewModel _vmCustomer;
  private CustomersViewModel _vmCustomers;
  ...
}
```

As viewmodels are created by CM, how can I connect my main shell to each instance of them? Or is this a wrong approach? I do not need a conductor in its canonical sense here, as I'm not activating or deactivating a set of panes like in a MDI: I have a SDI UI with some panes, each backed by its VM, and a main shell which should manipulate all them. What is the right approach in a similar scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your MainView.xaml add two ContentControls and give them names that match the names of two properties representing your ViewModels.

ViewModel:

```
public CustomerViewModel CustomerViewModel { get; set; }
public CustomersViewModel CustomersViewModel { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="CustomerViewModel" />
<ContentControl x:Name="CustomersViewModel" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the right clue. As for injecting the VM's, I suppose I can just add [Import] to the properties, as I'm using a MEF bootstrapper, and let CM create the VM's.

Comment: Yes or you can inject them in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is

```
public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }
```

and

```
<myApp:CustomerView cal:View.Model="{Binding Customer}/>
```

This gives a reader a better idea **what to expect from the view**. Blendability could be better, too.